# Really slow connection between wireless routers - wireless interference or something else?

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, dd-wrt, wds

I've got a bit of an issue with my home network.

Three TP-Link WR1043ND V2 are used in the setup and the idea is to get a wireless signal to all three floors of the building. All three routers are using DD-WRT latest firmware.

The ADSL modem (it could also act as a wireless router, but the quality of this device is lacking) is connected to the first router, on the first floor. It's running in WDS AP mode, to allow the other two routers to connect. Also, I'm using the wireless channel 11 as all nearby networks seem to be running on channels 1-6.

The other two routers are placed on the ground and second floor in the building - each running in WDS Station mode as well as exposing a second, virtual AP with the same parameters as the main network (to actually allow other wireless clients to connect).

I know a router running as a wireless repeater has about half the bandwidth available normally, but I've noticed severe connections issues.

If, instead of a wireless router (remember - those routers have 3 dedicated, pretty good antennas each!) I turn on my laptop on either the ground or second floor, I may not get all the "bars" in Windows, but I definitely get good speeds. As it is, the routers, from the usual 300Mbps drop to... 45Mbits. Or even lower, sometimes. Strangely, at times the speeds seem to pick up too (but that seems to be rare).

I don't know what to do. Obviously the best course of action would be to hook the extra routers using Ethernet cables, but that's impossible, sadly. And given that the signal strength seems to be pretty good if I test it using my laptop, and that the routers have pretty good antennas (or at least, so it would seem), I'd expect them to get a very good connection to each other.

Is there anything I can do to try and troubleshoot this issue? If there are any further tests I should do to provide more information, please let me know, and I'll do whatever I can.

Comment: Possibly the routers are interfering with eachother. Try 2 routers instead of 3 for a day or two and see if that helps.

Comment: @agtoever I got the third rather recently (the one on the ground floor), but it was already pretty bad before that. I COULD set each with a different SSID - I don't know if this matters or not however.